# Need to identify a short story about luminous energy being guiding a spaceship and in contact with a telepath on board.

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

In this story the guide is outside the ship and he and the telepath love each other.  They run into a black hole and he pushes the ship to safety but falls into the singularity.  she hears him all her life.

Comment: I think people will need more information than that. Any more you can remember on the story? Character names? Language/nationality? Age of the story? Where you read the story (e.g. in an anthology)?

Comment: @Moogle If you've read the story the above description is enough to trigger a memory; the ending of the story is unforgettable.  The only trouble I had was somehow recalling the useless title "Kyrie".  As it happened "telepath black hole time dilation" was enough for Google to work its magic.

Answer (score 10):

The short story is "Kyrie" by Poul Anderson.  This summary is lifted directly from the Wikipedia article ["Black holes in fiction."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_holes_in_fiction)

> "Kyrie" (1968): a short story written by Poul Anderson. An expedition exploring a fresh supernova remnant emerges from jump to face an electromagnetic nebular storm as it draws close to the cataclysm's residual black hole (Anderson mentions its Schwartzschild radius, but uses the terms "supernova core" and "star's exposed heart" to refer to the hole itself); their ship faces imminent destruction by an immense crackling globe of ionized gas that is on course to collide with it. Rescue is effected by Lucifer, a plasma-based being allied to the ship, who can communicate instantaneously over unlimited distances with the ship's onboard telepath. Exhausted by the effort of fending off the deadly hazard, Lucifer finally tumbles into the black hole, his death agonies stretched to forever in her mind as his entanglement in the hole's gravitational field slows his clock asymtotically to zero at the event horizon. She will never stop hearing his screams, and there is no place in the universe where she will find peace.

Comment: This one should be required reading, and is a good one to give to people who think you can't do literature in Science Fiction. Short and haunting.